# How to list the specific countries in a df which have NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created the df_nan below which shows the sum of NaN values from the main df, which, as seen, shows how many are in each specific column.

However, I want to create a new df, which has a column/index of countries, then another with the number of NaN values for the given country.

```
Country   Number of NaN Values
Aruba      4
Finland    3
```

I feel like I have to use groupby, to create something along the lines of this below, but .isna is not an attribute of the groupby function. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
df_nan2= df_nan.groupby(['Country']).isna().sum()
```

Current code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import spearmanr

# given dataframe df
df = pd.read_csv('countries.csv')

df.drop(columns= ['Population (millions)', 'HDI', 'GDP per Capita','Fish Footprint','Fishing Water',
                  'Urban Land','Earths Required', 'Countries Required', 'Data Quality'], axis=1, inplace = True)


df_nan= df.isna().sum()
```

Head of main df

```
0           Afghanistan  Middle East/Central Asia                0.30               0.20              0.08              0.18                        0.79      0.24          0.20         0.02               0.50                           -0.30
1               Albania   Northern/Eastern Europe                0.78               0.22              0.25              0.87                        2.21      0.55          0.21         0.29               1.18                           -1.03
2               Algeria                    Africa                0.60               0.16              0.17              1.14                        2.12      0.24          0.27         0.03               0.59                           -1.53
3                Angola                    Africa                0.33               0.15              0.12              0.20                        0.93      0.20          1.42         0.64               2.55                            1.61
4   Antigua and Barbuda             Latin America                 NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN                        5.38       NaN           NaN          NaN               0.94                           -4.44
5             Argentina             Latin America                0.78               0.79              0.29              1.08                        3.14      2.64          1.86         0.66               6.92                            3.78
6               Armenia  Middle East/Central Asia                0.74               0.18              0.34              0.89                        2.23      0.44          0.26         0.10               0.89                           -1.35
7                 Aruba             Latin America                 NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN                       11.88       NaN           NaN          NaN               0.57                          -11.31
8             Australia              Asia-Pacific                2.68               0.63              0.89              4.85                        9.31      5.42          5.81         2.01              16.57                            7.26
9               Austria            European Union                0.82               0.27              0.63              4.14                        6.06      0.71          0.16         2.04               3.07                           -3.00
10           Azerbaijan  Middle East/Central Asia                0.66               0.22              0.11              1.25                        2.31      0.46          0.20         0.11               0.85                           -1.46
11              Bahamas             Latin America                0.97               1.05              0.19              4.46                        6.84      0.05          0.00         1.18               9.55                            2.71
12              Bahrain  Middle East/Central Asia                0.52               0.45              0.16              6.19                        7.49      0.01          0.00         0.00               0.58                           -6.91
13           Bangladesh              Asia-Pacific                0.29               0.00              0.08              0.26                        0.72      0.25          0.00         0.00               0.38                           -0.35
14             Barbados             Latin America                0.56               0.24              0.14              3.28                        4.48      0.08          0.00         0.02               0.19                           -4.29
15              Belarus   Northern/Eastern Europe                1.32               0.12              0.91              2.57                        5.09      1.52          0.30         1.71               3.64                           -1.45
16              Belgium            European Union                1.15               0.48              0.99              4.43                        7.44      0.56          0.03         0.28               1.19                           -6.25
17                Benin                    Africa                0.49               0.04              0.26              0.51                        1.41      0.44          0.04         0.34               0.88                           -0.53
18              Bermuda             North America                 NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN                        5.77       NaN           NaN          NaN               0.13                           -5.64
19               Bhutan              Asia-Pacific                0.50               0.42              3.03              0.63                        4.84      0.28          0.34         4.38               5.27                            0.43
```

Nan head

```
Country                            0
Region                             0
Cropland Footprint                15
Grazing Footprint                 15
Forest Footprint                  15
Carbon Footprint                  15
Total Ecological Footprint         0
Cropland                          15
Grazing Land                      15
Forest Land                       15
Total Biocapacity                  0
Biocapacity Deficit or Reserve     0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you want to get Null count for each Country from "Cropland Footprint" column, then you can use the following code -

```
Unique_Country = df['Country'].unique()
Col1 = 'Cropland Footprint'

NullCount = []
for i in Unique_Country:
    s = df[df['Country']==i][Col1].isnull().sum()
    NullCount.append(s)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': Unique_Country,
              'Number of NaN Values': NullCount})
df2 = df2[df2['Number of NaN Values']!=0]
df2
```

**Output** -

```
Country              Number of NaN Values 
Antigua and Barbuda   1                    
Aruba                 1                    
Bermuda               1
```

If you want to get Null Count from another Column then just change the Value of Col1 variable.

Comment: @mr Is this solution working fine for you ?